# Numba namedtuple signature

Tags: python-3.x, signature, numba, namedtuple

I'm trying to specify the return type for a namedtuple in Numba and I am not able to do so. Could someone help? Consider the following minimal code:

```
import numba as nb
from   collections import namedtuple

NT = namedtuple('NT',['sum','sum2'])

@nb.njit((nb.types.NamedTuple([nb.float64,nb.float64],NT))(nb.int64,nb.float64[:,:]),fastmath=True)
def arrsum_njit(nn,xx):
    arraysum = 0.0
    out = NT(sum=arraysum,sum2=arraysum)
    return out
```

I get the error

```
No conversion from NT(float64 x 2) to NT(float64, float64) for '$20return_value.7', defined at None

File "numbanamedtuple.py", line 10:
def arrsum_njit(nn,xx):
    <source elided>
    out = NT(sum=arraysum,sum2=arraysum)
    return out
    ^

During: typing of assignment at numbanamedtuple.py (10)

File "numbanamedtuple.py", line 10:
def arrsum_njit(nn,xx):
    <source elided>
    out = NT(sum=arraysum,sum2=arraysum)
    return out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is "overoptimized" numba compiler (bug). Add a variable of a different type to the tuple to tell the compiler to use a heterogeneous tuple (internal class).

```
import numba as nb
from   collections import namedtuple

NT = namedtuple('NT',['sum','sum2','dummy'])

@nb.njit((nb.types.NamedTuple([nb.float64,nb.float64,nb.int64],NT))(nb.int64,nb.float64[:,:]),fastmath=True)
def arrsum_njit(nn,xx):
    arraysum = 0.0
    out = NT(sum=arraysum,sum2=arraysum,dummy=1)
    return out
```

**Upd:**
Tested:

- Numba 0.51.2/ Windows
- Numba 0.48.0/ Google colab - Linux Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Comment: Hmm. I'm using Numba 0.51.2  and your solution does not work for me.

 ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "numbanamedtuple.py", line 33, in <module>
    out = arrsum_njit(nn,xx)
  File "/home/gokhalen/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 608, in _explain_matching_error
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: No matching definition for argument type(s) int64, array(float64, 1d, C)```

Comment: @Nachiket I'm using the same Numba version, but Windows... (not Linux). And I tested Google Colab (Numba 0.48.0, Linux Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS). It's ok too.

Comment: Sorry, I made a stupid mistake while testing. I misinterpreted the error message. Works for me too. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Use `NamedUniTuple` instead. It's a numba spec type for homogeneous namedtuples.